# How to display all blobs (images) form database

Tags: php

Ok so i uploaded images with code below but i dont know how to display it, i want to make gallery so all i want is to display all images on one page, if you could explain that would be helpfull too!

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "phplogin";

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$ime = $_POST['ime'];


if(!isset($file))
{
    echo "Izaberite sliku";
}
else
{
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    if($image_size == FALSE)
    {
        echo "Niste izabrali dobru sliku";
    }
    else
    {
        if(!$insert = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image','$ime')"))
        {
            echo "Problem sa postavljanjem slike";
        }
        else
        {
            //$lastid = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
            // I WANT TO DISPLAY IMAGES HERE
            //echo "Image uploaded.<p />Slika:<p /><img src=get.php>";
        }
    }
}
```

?>

This code is to get image but it only display last ID and i dont know how to make it display all images

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databaseimage") or die(mysql_error());

$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$image = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id=$id");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $image;
```

?>

Comment: You posted a code for uploading the images. what have you tried so far to display it?

Comment: Its not a good practice to save images as blobs. Save the url to the image in the db instead and the image as a file to some folder. Then all you have to retrieve is the image url to the file

Comment: How i could i save url from folder to db can you show me example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save images as files instead of blobs. Store url to image in db as varchar

The html

`<form role="form" class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
       <div class="form-group">
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image"/>
</div>

 <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload" />
           </form>`

php

```
 define('UPLOAD_PATH','images/');
```

This is the constant for the path of the images. In this case its a folder named images in the same directory as the script you are working on

```
$errors = array();


 function output_errors($errors){
   $output=array();

  foreach($errors as $error){

  $output[]='<li>'.$error.'</li>';
  }
     return  '<ul>'.implode('',$output).'</ul>';

  }

 if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

    if(!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){

        $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $image_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
        $image_size=$_FILES['image']['size'];

         if((($image_type=='image/gif') || ($image_type=='image/jpeg') || ($image_type=='image/png') || ($image_type=='image/pjpeg')) &&
         ($image_size>0) /*&& ($image_size<=MAX_FILE_SIZE)*/){             

           if($_FILES['image']['error']==0){

                 /*give each image a unique name*/
                  $image=microtime().$image;

                 /*move uploaded file to permanent folder*/         
                 $target=UPLOAD_PATH.$image;

                 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target)){

                      if(mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO images(`image`) VALUES ('$image')") ){

                        $message="Image was uploaded sucessfully";
                      }else{
                       $errors[]="Error,image was not uploaded successfully";
                       /*delete permanent file from server*/
                       @unlink(UPLOAD_PATH.$image);
                      }                     

                 }/*end of move uploaded file*/
            } 


         }else{
            $errors[]="File uploaded must be of type png, jpeg or gif";

            /*delete temporary image file*/
            @unlink($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
         }/*end of image validation*/

    }else{
       $errors[]="Please select an image file";

    }/*empty*/

}





  if(!empty($errors))echo output_errors($errors);

  if(!empty($message)) echo $message;
```

Your images table could appear like this

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `image_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

To get an image from db, you could have a query that selects `image` from table images. To display image in html do

```
  $queryImage=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `image` FROM images");

    while($rowImage=mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryImage)){?>            

        <img src="<?php echo UPLOAD_PATH.$rowImage['image'] ;?>" style="width:250px; height:200px"/>    

    <?php
    }/*end of while loop getting images*/?>
```

Comment: But its not inserting it db? In your code what should i insert in db? Also in that query should i select all from image to display it?

Comment: You should insert `$image` into the db only since am presuming your `image_id` is an auto increment. `mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO images(`image`) VALUES ('$image')")` In the query you should select `image` only since its the only information you require.

Comment: I have modified the answer, replaced `insert_image` function with what you can work with

Comment: Idk whats wrong nothing happen when i run code i dont get errors or anything

Comment: Maybe thats because am storing my errors in an array. I like to store all errors and messages in an array and display them at once if need be. I have modified the answer

Comment: Wow its better now, beside this: Use of undefined constant UPLOAD_PATH - assumed 'UPLOAD_PATH'                    it uploaded in base but i get that small "broken" picture icon when using <img src="<?php echo $image?>"/>

Comment: Doe the page where you want to display in the same directory as the images folder?

Comment: Ok everything work and it store images in folder "images" but it dont display it in browser , instead i have that broken image icon. I used only <img src="<?php echo $image?>"/> to display image should i put something else?

Comment: Oh my bad...you should echo plus the `UPLOAD_PATH` constant. I have modified answer above

Comment: Thanks it work but how i remove picture,i deleted it from 'images' folder but then it appear like this: https://postimg.org/image/4v36o1gzl/

Comment: Also is it possible to when i press on that picture it open new page with description of picture?

Comment: you should remove the image path from the database also if you have removed it from the folder. Actually its not appropriate to do it manually, you should have an admins page for that. To have a caption of the picture displayed you should modify the `images`table to have a field for the caption. Then modify the form for uploading images to also include a textarea for the caption. To have an image display a description of the image, pass in the id of the image to the url to that page then use `GET` and display description for that id

Comment: Also if the code above worked for you please tick it so that it gets removed from the list of un-answered questions. Good luck coding

Comment: Yeah sure, but i was thinking its clickable, like when i upload picture in code new page is created and when i press on picture its <a href> to new page?  Btw i cant remove images from database so i need to delete it from code or?

Comment: `<a href="url?id=echo image_id from db"><img src=""/></a>` echo the image id as value to id and use `GET` to retrieve it the other page. Yes delete images from database in code